# "Package system is broken" and "unable to make backup link" combination in 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

I checked the similar Questions which indeed show resemblance to my problem but none of the previously presented solutions work for me.

When I try to install anything with Software Center a dependency error is returned:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

cpp-4.8: Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1 is installed
         Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is installed
gcc-4.8: Depends: cpp-4.8 (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is installed
         Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1 is installed
         Depends: libgcc-4.8-dev (>= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1 is installed
         Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is installed
```

And when I let the Software Center to attempt to repair it, I always get:

```
Preparing to unpack .../cpp-4.8_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cpp-4.8 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) over (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cpp-4.8_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of `./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1' before installing new version: Input/output error
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cpp-4.8_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gcc-4.8:
 gcc-4.8 depends on cpp-4.8 (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1); however:
```

As I state above, I tried the suggested solutions like:

```
 sudo apt-get clean
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt-get -f install
```

I also tried to remove packages without success.
The dependency problem keeps occurring and ultimately I end up with 
unable to make backup link of `./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1` message. `dpkg -S /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1` returns `cpp-4.8: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1` if it helps any.

My ubuntu version is 14.04, (Description: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS).

At the moment I cannot install or uninstall anything.
Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you try an "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" ? (different that one apt-get upgrade)

Comment: I'm not sure what happened here, but it might help to remove all the GCC 4.8 packages and re-install them as a way out of this seemingly inconsistent state.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yup, tried dist-upgrade, received the same "following packages have unmet dependencies" on cpp-4.8 and gcc-4.8. then tried with -f which led to "unable to make backup link of" again.